# UICollectionView with data source fetched from Photos - slow updates with big amount of photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I am making [the app](http://borisy.net/altershot) for detecting screenshots in Photos library using old `ALAseetLibrary` framework — please use new Photos framework if you can. My problem is, when user has big photo library it takes a lot of time to find screenshots. I am updating my data source every time app is opened.

Here's the code for scanning the photo library:

```
ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock savedPhotosBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if (group)
    {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
             if(result)
             {
                 ALAssetRepresentation *original = [result defaultRepresentation];
                 CGSize dimensions = [original dimensions];
```

After this work is finished I am calling `reloadData()`. How can I update the data on the go so it is possible to interact with `UICollectionView` while its data source is updating?

Answer (score 0):

You should use performBatchUpdate method. 
create array with new indexPath to be added.
call insertItemsAtIndexPaths:

instead of reloadData